# How to pull new files from github to Visual Studio?

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio, github

I'm new to developing on Windows and getting frustrated with how non-intuitive Visual Studio feels compared to Eclipse. Here's where I'm at:

- I created a local VS project, and wrote some code.
- I pushed the code to github via the built-in source control options. No problems, source is all there.
- My collaborator made new files, and commited them to github. Those are up and live.
- I pulled from github, but I don't see the files anywhere in my solution. Where are they? How can I get them to automatically add to my VS project?

How do I pull **ALL** files on github into VS without having to manual download them and add them to my solution? Visual Studio version is 2019 Community edition.

**--EDIT--**

I finally found them by switching my solution explorer to the project's folder view using the "Switch Views" button at the top of the solution explorer pane. **How do I add these to the solution view?**

The concept of having a "solution" completely abstracted from the actual file contents is... strange. I think I'm just going to back to Eclipse. I want to like VS because of vast amount of content in it, but the user experience has been a much more hostile learning environment.

Comment: I finally found them by switching my solution explorer to the project's folder view using the "Switch Views" button at the top of the solution explorer pane. The concept of having a "solution" completely abstracted from the actual file contents is... strange. I think I'm just going to back to Eclipse. I want to like VS because of vast amount of content in it, but the user experience feels much more hostile than learning eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with Windows nor Visual Studio; this is a Git issue.

here are some steps to follow:

1. make sure that you are pushing to the same branch. checkout this [link](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches)
2. if you are pushing into different branch make sure that you do `rebasing`. checkout this [link](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase)

Comment: Mahmood, it is indeed a VS issue (the issue being my understanding of VS), not a git issue. they are indeed both on `master`, and we are not rebasing. I found the source of my misunderstanding, see my edit.